# Ideal language to use to code a multi step order form

Tags: php, forms, html, dynamic, webforms

I need to create a multi step dynamic order form. There will be 3-4 pages of questions. When someone makes a choice there is a div summary at the end with all the choices made. The client can then edit a choice by clicking that entries edit link. The form will contain text boxes, bullets and a dynamic google map. At the end of this process i want to get an email with the google map as well as the choices.

I am not looking for someone to help me do this whole thing, i am just looking for someone to point me in the right direction so that i can research the appropriate technology required to make this work. I will be using Google Static Maps Api v2 and jquery. Would prefer to keep this as a html5 doc but php is ok too.

Any advice?

Comment: There are some pretty significant differences between HTML5 and PHP, and the two are far from mutually exclusive.  If you're trying to decide between them then it sounds like you don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish or how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a pretty standard dynamic order form.  You can use html5 for the input types, but other than that I wouldn't use any specific html5 technology (unless you really wanted local storage in case someone left accidentally and came back or something).  If you know PHP, it would work fine as a back end for the post fields with `_SESSION`.

This is not an extreme project, so it shouldn't be hard to find resources on how you can do this with HTML/PHP.  Why not start with a simpler form and build from there?

Comment: I guess i can code it in html as one page, break it up with css and jquery. At the end for the div that receives what a user picked i can make a jquery function to collect the inputs. Seems simple enough. In your opinion do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: @Bart that sounds fine, but you do need a couple layers of persistence (i.e. a session and probably a database).  PHP can handle that for you, or any server-side language.  If you want to do it only on the client side, you'll have to use cookies or local storage, and I wouldn't recommend that at all.